# How to read content of a web page through a Java program?

Tags: java, web-scraping

I am planning to write a Java program to read some exchange rates from a web site (http://www.doviz.com) and was wondering what is the best approach to only read (or read the whole and strip the parts needed) the content that I need.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check out [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/). It's quite easy to use, powerful, and the price is right!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My advice is to use the [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) library

It's very easy to parse an external content with a css/jquery-like syntax

```
// Only one line to parse an external content
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://jsoup.org").get();

// "Javascript-like" syntax
Element content = doc.getElementById("content");
Elements links = content.getElementsByTag("a");
for (Element link : links) {
  String linkHref = link.attr("href");
  String linkText = link.text();
}

// "Jquery/Css-like" syntax
Elements resultLinks = doc.select("h3.r > a");
Elements pngs = doc.select("img[src$=.png]");
```

Just add the jsoup.jar library to your classpath and enjoy !
Open-Source and free to use of course.

Comment: Thank you for taking the JSoup to the table, I'm using httpclient for usecases like above but I will certainly investigate JSoup. Is it also possible to read protected pages with login?

Comment: It's possible to add headers informations, so i think it's possible. http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url

Comment: If you need a complexe navigation (form post, redirection), HttpClient is a good idea to get either directly html content to be parsed with Jsoup or the login cookie, and inject it into the connection jsoup (`Jsoup.connect("http://example.com").cookie("auth", "cookies data")`)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to implement an RSS reading mechanism of a webpage (programatically) and extract the content of the RSS xml using standard parsers.